# not able to display large tree structure with divs

Tags: html, css

On a JSP page, we have displayed a tree like structure using nested divs.Width of each div is calculated at run time. Only width of "div1" is given at runtime and other div's width is calculated using this at run time.Here, I have set it to 200px.

```
<div id="div1" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:200px;float:left;overflow:auto">
    <div id="div2" style="background-color:yellow;height:200px;width:190px;">
        <div id="div3" style="background-color:blue;height:180px;width:180px;"></div>
        <div id="div4" style="background-color:red;height:180px;width:50px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the issue is "div4" is not getting appended in the right of "div3". It is getting placed in next line. Because of that tree structure is getting disturbed. And if I increase the width of "div2" then it is placed in the right but then horizontal scroll bar is coming for all cases where it is not required.
I have noticed the behavior of div that it place text vertically rather than horizontally. 
Any idea how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind? I created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r6sPY/

Div4 will never get appended to the right of div3 as long as the width of div2 will be smaller than the sum of div3 and div4. But then again, I am not sure if this is what you had in mind.

```
<div id="div1" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:200px;float:left;overflow:auto">
<div id="div2" style="background-color:yellow;height:200px;width:190px;">
    <div id="div3" style="background-color:blue;height:180px;width:130px;float:left;"></div>
    <div id="div4" style="background-color:red;height:180px;width:50px;float:left;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if that's what you want you use the edited code i've entered on this answer. notice that the width of div3 is changed in my code, and i've also added a left float to div3 and div4